# Return open bars - midnight issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having my script that looks like this

```
SELECT name FROM restaurants WHERE
(mon_o < mon_c AND "18:00" BETWEEN mon_o AND mon_c)
OR
(mon_o > mon_c AND ("18:00" > mon_o OR "18:00" < mon_c))
```

This script returns all open restaurants.
**mon_o** = Monday opening time *(MySQL TIME type, hh:mm)*
**mon_c** = Monday closing time *(MySQL TIME typem hh:mm)*
**18:00** is the current time in this example.

This scripts works as it should, but I want to extend this script to now also allow bars to enter a closing time after 24:00, so for example:
Opening time at **15:00**, Closing time at **02:00** would not work well with this script, and that's my problem that I can't figure out.
I'm using 24-hour format

Comment: Your logic looks like it should work.

Comment: When closing time is less than opening time, add 24 hours to the closing time, then do the BETWEEN comparison.

Answer (score 0):

One simple adjustment to the query will get you most of the way:

To do the comparison when closing time is earlier than opening time, compare to the closing time plus 24 hours.

You can use the `ADDTIME()` function to add 24 hours.

```
SELECT name FROM restaurants WHERE
(mon_o < mon_c AND '18:00' BETWEEN mon_o AND mon_c)
OR
(mon_o > mon_c AND ('18:00' > mon_o OR '18:00' < ADDTIME(mon_c,'24:00:00')))
                                                 ^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Of course, if someone is checking for restaurants open at 01:00 on Tuesday morning, for a restaurant that's open from '11:00' to '2:00' on monday, you'd need to compare to the "monday" columns, and not the "tuesday" columns to get a match.

(It's not clear why you'd use a `>=` and `<=` comparisons for one condition (closing time later than open time) which is what the `BETWEEN` does; and use `>` and `<` comparisons for the other condition.)